# Kibana 4 Metric visualization show latest value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'm new to Kibana and Elastic Search and i have run into this problem:

My ES contains (among other stuff) also data containing the current value of one custom performance counter and i would like my dashboard to show this value, e.g., as a big number - therefore i tried to use the Metric visualization, but i have no idea on how to show only the last value. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: note - this is referenced in https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar issue for our use case. We found two ways to handle it:

1. If the data is periodically generated then you can use the Kibana feature of showing data of recent n days to see the latest data.
2. In our case, the above option was not possible so we went with a hack where we have a property in our documents called "IsLatest" so we apply a filter "IsLatest":true in all our charts where we need latest info. We have written our code which feeds data to ElasticSearch in such a way that it updates the older data and sets it's "IsLatest" to false.

Hope it helps